# Кто портит сертификат у файла?

Tags: сертификат, вирусы, dll

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с проблемой. Все модули программы подписываются нашим сертификатом и при подгрузки в память проверяется их сертификат. Если сертификат не проходит проверку, то такой модуль не загружается.

Так вот проблема следующая. Время от времени пользователи жалуются, что некоторые модули программы перестают грузиться (не все)... при получении модулей обратно, мы проверили, сертификаты вроде как наши, но файл физически изменен (не проходит проверку при сравнении побайтовом с тем, что мы высылали ему изначально, с файлом который шел в дистрибутиве продукта).

Предположительно, какой-то вирь или троян себя внедряет в модуль и антивирус (пока предположительно nod32 и drweb) заботливо его от туда вычищает, тем самым нарушается целостность модуля...

Есть предположения, что троянчик все же ковыряет файлы...

Хотелось бы узнать, действительно такое может быть? И если есть примеры, кто может модифицировать файлы, то был бы признателен. На данный момент, мы никак не может выцепить зверя, который у пользователей портит наши модули, а пользователи, мучают нас своими звонками =)

**PS: Добавлена информация в ответе**

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь

---

**...В продолжение темы...**

Сегодня у одной DLL была "испорчена" цифровая подпись во внутренней сети, следовательно воздействие вирусов, антивирусов можно отбросить с 99% вероятностью. DLL, на всякий случай была проверена антивирусом отдельно, антивирус ничего не показал... По уверению пользователя, который пользовался программой, он говорит, что просто регистрировал и разрегистрировал модули программные, после какого-то момента цифровая подпись у DLL стала недействительна.

Исходя из вышесказанного, остается вопросом, кто, если не вирус может изменить DLL.

PS: К сожалению сравнить этот модуль с оригиналом не удастся, т.к. оригинальный файл не сохранился :-(

Может ли винда дурить при LoadLibrary() с DLL имеющие цифровые подписи? Может ли проверка сертификата у DLL нарушать целостность этого самого сертификата?

---

**Продолжение истории:** Отправил dll касперскому пару недель назад, жду результатов... Интересно на сколько скоро придет ответ? =)

Comment: А может, антивирус ничего не детектит и не вычищает? Попробуй найти различающиеся куски и посмотреть их в дизассемблере, может что интересное заметишь.

Comment: есть такой плагин к IDA, называется patchdiff2. используй в своих целях )

Comment: Различие в "состав цифровой подписи"/"дополнительно"/"Проверенные атрибуты"/"Выборка сообщения"...
В самих сертификатах не смыслю особо, потому не знаю, какое поле для чего нужно, и что оно по смыслу означает. Остальные поля совпадают у оригинального файла и измененного (присланного пользователем). Ну и как понятно, признак у файла стоит "Сертификат не действителен".

Comment: @Flammable, как вы себе представляете анализ и сравнение всех команд под дизассемблером между валидной и невалидной версией? Ведь их там может быть более 500000, раз это полноценный модуль !

Comment: >> как вы себе представляете анализ и сравнение всех команд под дизассемблером между валидной и невалидной версией?

Никак не представляю. Очевидно, что сначала надо сравнивать, а потом смотреть в дизассемблере отличающиеся куски.

Comment: @Francesco, многие рутинные действия давно и успешно автоматизируются. но дело не в этом. если проблема лишь в длл - просто обновить их на изначальные. если проблема с вирусом - пусть пользователь чистит комп, это не проблема разработчика. но и разработчик может пойти на встречу пользователю, просто дав возможность восстановить файлы(переустановка).

Comment: @vv2cc, @Flammable

В общем более детально посмотрел я на эти два файла (оригинал и присланный). Отличаются на ~500 байт по размеру (присланный пользователем больше). Команда fc.exe /b по двум файлам показала различия с 110f смещения до конца файла. Результат сравнения уместился в 32Мб текстовый файл (dll ~5,5мб).

Обе dll проверены на virustotal, 45 антивирусов говорят о чистом файле.

Возможно различие при по байтовом сравнении ложное, т.к. что-то в начале файла было дописано, а далее естественно, все смещено и сравнение не имеет никакого смысла. Можно еще как-то сравнить файлы?

Comment: @vv2cc

Сейчас так и делается, восстанавливается исходный вариант файла, просто такие случаи участились, и нужно как-то решать проблему уже более глобально, чтобы не мучались пользователи, а мы сразу могли предоставить решение. Сканирование пользовательской машины на наличие вирусов ничего не показывает. Файлы изменяются. То что мы восстанавливаем файл, не дает гарантии, что он через пару дней (любой другой период времени) изменится вновь.

Comment: @pincher1519 скажи, что даст тебе это, особенно если там нет вирусного кода?

Comment: @pincher1519, а на время изменения смотрели? 

Если оно "подкручено", то это явно злонамеренные действия, а иначе (время измененного больше, чем время установки оригинала) это может быть какой-то ошибкой в Вашей системе. (естественно, здесь я фантазирую, поскольку детали ее работы нам неизвестны)

Comment: > Но т.к. возможно где-то в начале файла было дописано 500 байт левой информации, ниже все соответственно тоже будет различаться.
IDA и плагин для нее patchdiff2 не подвержены данной проблеме

Comment: @pincher1519, в сети полно программ, которые разумно выдают diff для двоичных файлов. 

    binary diff

в гугле.

Comment: @pincher1519

Ну найдете вы эти 500 байт. Что в с ними дальше делать будете. С высокой вероятностью все эти 500 байт будут 00 - тот кусок, где DrWEB потер либо тело вируса, либо бакап таблицы импорта.

Заюзайте уже тогда лучше тот же [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/download-pe-explorer.htm) и проверить, чтоб в старом и новом файле сходились все адреса (и длины) секций, а также собственно таблицы...

Какой вы адрес писали 110f да... в этих краях вполне могла раньше начинаться секция .text - обычно немного меньше конечно, но у вас DLL 5Mb - так что может и так быть быть.

Comment: @pincher1519: ответ на оба вопроса -- однозначно нет. Ищите, кто изменяет DLL. Попробуйте воспроизвести эту ситуацию и воспользуйтесь [Process Monitor'ом](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), только настройте фильтры, чтобы не читать гигабайты ненужных логов.

Comment: @pincher1519, а на время изменения dll и файла с подписью смотрели?

Comment: @avp неизмено, насколько можно судить. Все модули остались от августа прошлого года. В том числе и тот, у которого стала не действительна подпись.

Comment: @pincher1519, тогда вирус (или злоумышленник). Т.е. кто-то (что-то) запоминает дату модификации, портит содержимое и (система-то тут дату поменяет) откатывает дату на запомненную.

Не думаю, что ошибки в программах так могут проявляться.

Answer (score 5):

Иходя из некоторого опыта общения с антивирами и всякими антиадварами в рамках администрирования не самой мелкой конторы, случаев, когда этот софт самостоятельно ломал файлы без причины замечено не было. Но 100% гарантии, что так не бывает - естественно не дам)

Мысль, что файл меняют вирусы и прочие бацилы - наиболее вероятна. Вся живность, которая внедряется в существующий ЕХЕшник (или DLLку) почти всегда меняет таблицу вызовов файла, чтоб когда пользователь запустил прогу или произошел вызов функции в DLL сначала выполнился код вируса, который уже в свою очередь может быть запустит родной код программы или библиотеки)) Естественно подпись такого файла не сойдется.

В ходе лечения антивир пытается реконструировать эту таблицу... в общем у него почти всегда получается сделать файл снова рабочим, но да вполне вероятно, что побайтово результат лечения и оригинал будут отличаться.

Подпись в любом из этих случаев не сойдется и это правильно - так как задача подписи - показать, если вдруг файл изменяли (или вирусы, или люди, или ещё какая-нибудь хрень - главное, что то, что есть не соответствует тому, что пописывали).

Что делать.... Самое первое, что приходит в голову - передавать по сети и хранить до запуска модули в запакованном/зашифрованном виде, чтоб они не интересовали всякий разный софт. Я не думаю, что это будет настолько накладно по вычислительным ресурсам.

Comment: Файлы, которые присылают пользователи, антивирусную проверку проходят успешно, т.е. если файл содержал вредоносный код, то его уже в нем нет. Но при всем этом они не жаловались на то, что их антивирус ругается на какую либо библиотеку нашу... Хотя пользователи такие пользователи :-)

Comment: @pincher1519

Вредоносный код может повреждать файл. А антивир восстанавливает по своему усмотрению, а не так, как было изначально. Я тут даже знакомых попинал - да. Вплоть до того, что меняется размер файла после лечения (относительно первоначального).

Шифруйте файлы (и не называйте их DLL). Перед загрузкой - распаковка в ТЕМР.

Comment: На текущим этапе это не возможно, т.к. dll регистрируются в системе, точнее COM объекты регистрируются из этих dll. Сейчас в принципе механизм извлечения объектов из модуля реализован, и вроде как даже работает, что позволяет использовать com-объекты без их регистрации в системе. Шифрование не тот выход... мы не боремся с заражением, мы защищаем приложение от подмены его модулей. Сейчас нам нужно найти причину (кто именно) изменяет модули программы.

Comment: Мы наверно говорим на разных языках (

Если вы работаете напрямую с DLL (а не юзаете механизмы в стиле VisualBasic, которые требовали регистрации СОМ-контейнера в системе и последующее создание СОМ-объекта по имени), что вам мешает сделать механизм который будет проверять целостность вашей DLL и в случае ошибки загружать с сервера правильную?

От подмены вы уже защитились, в случае искажений в файле - он не работает, как и положенно))

Comment: Теперь вам нужно сделать что-то, чтоб файл не изменялся. Одним из вероятных предположений, так как это исполняемый модуль является вирусная активность - значит нужно сделать так, чтоб фаши модули не были интересны бацилам.

Вероятность того, что их меняют ещё какие-нибудь сканеры или системы защиты конечно есть, но она очень мала; и отлавливать её нужно явно не здесь))

Вероятность того, что файлы ковыряют люди - практически исключена - никакой ломатель не признается в этом добровольно, и уж точно не будет вам присылать результаты своих изысканий мотивируя тем, что "не работает")))

Comment: Образно говоря изменять ваши файлы (относительно первоначального вида) может любая программа находящаяся на компьютере клиента, у которой достаточно прав на запись в папку, где лежит ваша:

- сам клиент руками;

- различные вредоносные программы, которых насчитывается несколько десятков тысяч;

- антивирусное ПО в процессе лечения файла;

- сканеры адвара, которые решили, что ваш метод загрузки объектов, не что иное, как новый способ всунуть рекламу бедному юзеру;

- злобный хакер Петя, который не хочет дать Марфе Васильевне работать и портит нужную ей программу)))